# Entire function that omits a value reaches every other value infinitely many times

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following: if $f$ is an entire function that omits $a\in \mathbb{C}$, then $f$ reaches $b\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{a\}$ infinitely many times.

I think this might have something to do with Picard's "little" theorem, but I don't know how to use it in this context. Also, I have tried this: suppose $\exists!z$ so that $f(z)=b$, let's call it $a_0$. Then one can define the entire function $h(z)=f(z)-b$, which has only one zero $(a_0)$. I don't know if I could use this in some way or if I am in the wrong path.

Comment: You are looking for the "Great Picard": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem